# Run a cmder/conemu task with bash script that executes a command but keeps running

Tags: bash, terminal, task, conemu, cmder

I have the following as a pre-defined task in Cmder which should open gitbash and then run a command (in this case im just using "ls" for simplicity) on startup but keep the shell open.

```
> -cur_console:d:%userprofile%\Coding\My_location -cur_console:t:"My Server" cmd /c ""%ConEmuDir%\..\git-for-windows\bin\bash" --login -i -c ls" -new_console:c
```

The problem is that the command runs and then asks to press Enter to close the terminal. I would like the terminal to remain open after running that command. Im guessing I have to change something with the "-c ls" but not sure what!

Thanks!

Comment: Change `-c ls` to `-c 'ls; exec bash'`

Comment: Amazing thank you Philippe!! Just out of curiosity, where did you find out about this from? It was very hard to find any good documentation about this.

Comment: For this particular one, it's from experience. `-c` takes a string which can contain multiple commands, which is why I put `ls` followed by `exec bash` which spawn another interactive shell.